Partition a range with respect to a value
What is the precondition of the algorithms std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound and std::equal_range?
template <class FwIt, class T>
FwIt             lower_bound(FwIt first, FwIt last, const T& val);

template <class FwIt, class T>
FwIt             upper_bound(FwIt first, FwIt last, const T& val);

template <class FwIt, class T>
pair<FwIt, FwIt> equal_range(FwIt first, FwIt last, const T& val);

Currently, there is a confusion on the internet:
The linked cplusplus.com documentations say that the given range [first, last) has to be partitioned with respect to val. This does not clarify anything, as std::partition and std::is_partitioned does not have a val parameter, instead they have a unary predicate pred.
template <class FwIt, class UnaryPredicate>
FwIt partition(FwIt first, FwIt last, UnaryPredicate pred);

template <class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
bool is_partitioned(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate pred);

The more prominent cppreference.com uses the term partitioned range [first, last), which is even more vague. See std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound and std::equal_range.

It's worth noting that a sorted sequence will always meet the partitioning requirements.

The source of information is the standard. It's the source of these sites too.
In this case we could use [alg.binary.search] from C++17. According to this the three functions have different preconditions: The elements e of [first, last) shall be partitioned with respect to

std::lower_bound: the expression e < value.
std::upper_bound: the expression !(value < e).
std::equal_range: the expressions e < value and !(value < e). Also, for all elements e of [first, last), e < value shall imply !(value < e).

In a table, where x ≤ y ::= y ≮ x ::= !(y < x):



Algorithm
Precondition




std::lower_bound(..., value)
std::is_partitioned(..., _ < value)


std::upper_bound(..., value)
std::is_partitioned(..., _ ≤ value)


std::equal_range(..., value)
std::is_partitioned(..., _ < value) && std::is_partitioned(..., _ ≤ value) && ∀e ∈ [first, last): e < value value ≮ e




Worth noting: None of the three algorithms you mention require strict-weak-ordering which is a bit relaxed when it comes to the standard algorithms.
